# What is the best way to run a Console Application once per day at a certain time?

Tags: c#, task-scheduler, windows-services

What is the best way to run a Console application (C#) once per day at a certain time on Windows XP? I want to see the Console window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Using Scheduled Tasks

---

***To open Scheduled Tasks***

-> click Start

-> click All Programs

-> point to Accessories

-> point to System Tools

-> click Scheduled Tasks.

***To schedule a new task:***

**1.** Double-click Add Scheduled Task to start the Scheduled Task Wizard, and then click Next in the first dialog box.

**2.** The next dialog box displays a list of programs that are installed on your computer, either as part of the Windows XP operating system, or as a result of software installation.

*Use one of the following procedures:*

> **i)** If the program that you want to run is listed, click the program, and then click Next.
>
> **ii)** If you want to run a program, script, or document that is not listed, click Browse, click the folder and file that you want to schedule, and then click Open.

**3.** Type a name for the task, and then choose one of the following options:

> - Daily
> - Weekly
> - Monthly
> - One time only
> - When my computer starts (before a user logs on)
> - When I log on (only after the current user logs on)

**4.** Click Next, specify the information about the day and time to run the task, and then click Next.

*Note that the information about the day and time to run the task vary depending on the selection that you made in the previous wizard dialog box. For example, if you chose Weekly, you must indicate the day of the week, the time, and if the task should run every week, every 2 weeks, every 3 weeks, and so on.

**5.** Type the name and password of the user who is associated with this task. Make sure that you choose a user with sufficient permissions to run the program. By default, the wizard selects the name of the user who is currently logged on.

**6.** Click Next, and then click Finish after you verify the choices that you have made.

Resource from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Comment: +1 I'll just add that it can even be used to turn the machine on to execute the scheduled tasks, which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Scheduled Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569). It does exactly that and lets you choose a specific interval.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the windows scheduler, something like:

```
at 5:00pm /interactive "c:\app.exe"
```

Or you can do it as a Windows Service and set "Interact with desktop" (or whatever it is called these days).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 you would use **Task Scheduler** 
(http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-open-task-scheduler-on-windows-10.html).

Way 1: Open it in the Start Menu.
Click the lower-left Start button, enter schedule in the empty box and select Schedule tasks from the results.

Way 2: Turn on Task Scheduler via Search.
Tap the Search button on the taskbar, type schedule in the blank box and choose Schedule tasks.

Way 3: Open it in the Control Panel.
Step 1: Access Control Panel.
Step 2: Find and tap Schedule tasks in System and Security.

Way 4: Open Task Scheduler in the Computer Management.
Step 1: Open Computer Management.
Step 2: Click Task Scheduler on the left.

Comment: Just an FYI, the `Scheduled Tasks` mentioned above is Windows XP's Task Scheduler.

Comment: @David - The link does not work for me.  This fact wouldn't be a big deal, if you had quoted the relevant information, from your link.  Consider doing that, so I can reverse my vote, and check the help center to understand the reason link-only answers are forwned upon here at Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thank you for your comment.  I have added the ways to find/open Task Scheduler on W10.  The link was provided to avoid a copy but I see your point that not all links would work.  I have left the link in my answer to provide images to those that may be able to access the link.